# Is Walter White dead?

Tags: character, breaking-bad

In the last episode, they don't actually show Walter White dying. They only show him lying on the floor.

Is it possible for them to continue the story from there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the narrative of the program, it seems that Walter White is dead. However, if one looks at how he was wounded it is conceivable that he wouldn't have died from the wound that he received and that he simply became unconscious at the end of the episode.

While an M-60 fires a 7.62 (.30 cal) round, its bullets are copper jacket military rounds. These rounds don't expand and often inflict non-fatal wounds if they don't strike major organs or blood vessels. As demonstrated in the episode "Felina", the series denouement, Walter isn't struck directly by a rounds but is hit by a ricochet. This could cause a serious injury and perhaps an incapacitating one; however death seems to be a stretch.

Assuming that Walt's injury (on his lower right side) could have struck his liver or his renal artery and thus caused him to bleed out internally. Unfortunately, such a wound would have made it impossible for him to have walked out of the neo-Nazi's hideout and around for what would have been at least ten minutes. Given that the police shown to have arrived within seconds of Walt's collapse, he could have easily been saved if paramedics had been called.

The series states that Walter White is dead. The injury that he received could have been easily survivable.

Answer (score 11):

Walter is definitely dead, even confirmed by [Walter White Tombstone](http://www.nydailynews.com/entertainment/tv-movies/breaking-bad-inspired-mock-tombstone-inspires-real-controvesy-article-1.1494107). It's official and even the next phase of the Breaking Bad universe is about Saul's story k.a. [Better Call Saul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Better_Call_Saul) and its a prequel.

Comment: Wasn't this a forgone conclusion at the start of the series that Walter was dieing of a brain tumor or some such? Never watched the show, but thought this was the whole reason Walther *broke bad* in the first place, was to support his family after his demise.

Comment: @Paulster2 its lung cancer and it got cured near the end of story.

Comment: Which is why I am talking about my butt ... and put this in a comment instead of an answer ;-) Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @Paulster2 its answering the question, so it doesn't appearing a comment to me.

Comment: The cancer was in remission, not cured, he still had the tumour and explained that remission did not mean cured. Later on in Season 4 he finds out the cancer is back (as evident by going back to Chemo, and getting the bag from the guy helping him in the cabin in season 5). He was on the terminal descent. He died with a smile on his face with a serious gunshot wound he had been walking around with while helping Jesse.

Comment: I have accepted this answer although I am a little unsure if the Walter White Tombstone was 'official'.

Comment: a) How is this official? The tombstone was erected by a charity to raise money. b) How does Better Call Saul, a spinoff set 6 years in the past, in any way confirm his death?